# Compare each bit of a string in Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a SQL query which needs to be converted into Python. I'm stucked in working on one condition.

```
if id != '[0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}0[0-9]{1}'
```

(Explanation [First 4 numbers] + [2 alphabet] + [0] + [0-9] + [1])
print(id)

How can I check this condition in Python?

Comment: Use Pythons regular expression library [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module to do that:

```
import re

if not re.match(r'[0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}0[0-9]{1}', id):
    # do something
```

**Edit:**

'r' here is not required but it's recommended. it means raw string (nothing in the string should be escaped), take a look at the following example:

```
>>> print('test\n')
test

>>> print(r'test\n')
test\n
```

For more details, please take a look at [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just wondering what 'r' denotes inside the bracket?